# Find a subtring in a string using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Suppose i have a string   `kk a.b.cjkmkc  jjkocc a.b.c.`

I want to find the substring `a.b.c` in the string , but it is not working.

Here is my code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a.b.c");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
int x = m.find()
```

Comment: What does `.` do in a regex?

Comment: Why not simply String.indexOf() ?

Answer (score 6):

The `.` in Java `Pattern` is a special character: "Any character (may or may not match line terminators)" (from the `java.util.regex.Pattern` [web page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

Try escaping it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a\\.b\\.c");
```

Also note:

- `Matcher.find` returns `boolean`, not `int`.
- `Pattern`s take double escapes

Comment: Easy mistake to make for those not familiar with regex +1 for quick and easy answer

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `.` is a special charater in regular expressions. You can let Java quote sepcial characters using [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). BTW: What about [String.indexof(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (which is faster). if you really need regular expressions, have a look at this:

```
String str = "kk a.b.cjkmkc jjkocc a.b.c.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("a.b.c"));
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    int x = m.start();
    // ...
}
```